# error 500 in response from Google cloud function to my web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I've set Google cloud function (Which works perfectly on testing) that fails to send a response back to frontend:

the error:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:81)
```

the cloud function:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
      (async () => {
    let se = []
    for (let i =0;i<req.body.url.length;i++){
      let se1 = req.body.searchPhrase + " site:" + req.body.url[i]
      se.push(se1.toString())
    }
         console.log(se)
    let scrape_job = {
        search_engine: 'bing',
        keywords: se,
        num_pages: '1',
    };
console.log(req.body.searchPhrase)
 results =  await se_scraper.scrape({}, scrape_job);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type:application/json');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "Challenges found !",
      results: "yes"
    });
  })();

};
```

I'm using axios.post to send the requests.

the frontend function:

```
 axios
 .post("https://us-central1-astute-loop-252111.cloudfunctions.net/scrap",newData)
 .then((res)=>{
   console.log(res)
   d = d.contact(res.data.results.results)
  })
```

Comment: Where are you running your backend and your frontend service? Are you using app-engine or they are running outside of the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: both frontend and backend is on app-engine, but this code is on cloud function and it get called with axios.post from frontend

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the way you send the request to the function, please? If the function is OK while testing it, maybe it can be an issue on the way you are sending the requests. Once an HTTP request is made, Axios returns a promise that is either fulfilled or rejected, depending on the response from the backend service. Are you handling the result using ¨then()¨ method ?

Comment: yes i am handaling the result with then(),